# R - Extract only first number after a specific line

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to extract a number from a long text. The below is part of the text. The number I need is after a specific line (i.e. AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON).

```
Number of Shares Beneficially Owned by Each Reporting Person With
      7.   SOLE VOTING POWER
                less than 1%
      8.   SHARED VOTING POWER
                26,732,516
      9.   SOLE DISPOSITIVE POWER
                3-4%
      10.  SHARED DISPOSITIVE POWER

11.  AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON
          26,733,210
12.  CHECK BOX IF THE AGGREGATE AMOUNT IN ROW (11) EXCLUDES
     CERTAIN SHARES*
                                              [ ]
13.  PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW (11)
          33.8%
14.  TYPE OF REPORTING PERSON
          IN
```

I would like to extract the number `26733210`

I tried the following codes

```
get.phares <- function(text)
{
  require(stringr)
  text <- tolower(text)
  text <- unlist(strsplit(text, "\n"))
  text <- text[which(str_detect(text,"[:graph:]"))]
  ind <- grep("aggregate\\+amount\\+beneficially\\+owned\\+by\\+each\\+reporting\\+person", text, perl = T)
  
  num_shares <- NA
  lines <- NULL
  ### first I check the next line, than line + 1 etc. up to line + 5
  for(i in 0:5)
  {
    #print(i)
    lines <- text[ind + i]
    
    ## Extract all numbers and commas
    num_shares <- unlist(regmatches(lines, gregexpr("[0-9,]+", lines)))
    ## Delete commas
    num_shares <- gsub(",", "", num_shares)
    ## Delete empty strings (when only one comma has been extracted)
    num_shares <- num_shares[num_shares != ""]
    num_shares <- as.numeric(num_shares)
    if(sum(num_shares) == 0) next
    #num_shares <- paste(num_shares,collapse = "|")
  
    return(num_shares)
  }
  return(num_shares)
}
```

But I found I could not get the variable `number_shares`, and R Console reported `Error in num_shares : object 'num_shares' not found`

I have attempted to improve my codes following relevant posts, but they did not work well on this issue. I would appreciate it if someone could help me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use `sub` here for a base R solution:

```
x <- "Number of Shares Beneficially Owned by Each ... AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON \n\n 26,733,210 ..."
num <- sub("^.*\\bAGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON\\s+(\\d{1,3}(?:,\\d{3})*)\\b.*$", "\\1", x)
num

[1] "26,733,210"
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. If I would like to extract the numbers from several texts which have similar format with the above but some of texts may use lowercase instead of capital letters here, may I know how to adjust the codes using `sub` ?

Comment: @zoe Pass `ignore.case=TRUE` as the fourth parameter to `sub`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple instances of this text to search, why not this?

```
library(stringr)
lapply(str_extract_all(text, "(AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON\n\\s+)[0-9,]+"), str_extract, pattern = "[0-9,]+")

[[1]]
[1] "26,733,210"
```

Or for a single instance

```
str_extract(str_extract(text, "(AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON\n\\s+)[0-9,]+"), "[0-9,]+")

[1] "26,733,210"
```

Comment: Your regex pattern for capturing a number with thousands separator is too broad, and could result in false positive matches.

Comment: @Tim can you please write one to explain!

Comment: Use: `\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*`

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out.  Your answer upvoted please.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an appropriate regex to extract the relevant number form the text.

```
get.pharse <- function(text) {
  sub('.*AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON\\s*(\\d+,.*?)\n.*', '\\1', text)
}

get.pharse(text)
#[1] "26,733,210"
```

If you want a number as output you could do :

```
get.pharse <- function(text) {
  readr::parse_number(sub('.*AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON\\s*(\\d+,.*?)\n.*', '\\1', text))
}

get.pharse(text)
#[1] 26733210
```

**data**

```
text = "Number of Shares Beneficially Owned by Each Reporting Person With
7.   SOLE VOTING POWER
less than 1%
8.   SHARED VOTING POWER
26,732,516
9.   SOLE DISPOSITIVE POWER
3-4%
10.  SHARED DISPOSITIVE POWER

11.  AGGREGATE AMOUNT BENEFICIALLY OWNED BY EACH REPORTING PERSON
26,733,210
12.  CHECK BOX IF THE AGGREGATE AMOUNT IN ROW (11) EXCLUDES
CERTAIN SHARES*
  [ ]
13.  PERCENT OF CLASS REPRESENTED BY AMOUNT IN ROW (11)
33.8%
14.  TYPE OF REPORTING PERSON
IN"
```

Comment: Many thanks Ronak. The codes are useful for me.